# How to add 2 links in sweet alert and laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

How to add 2 links in sweet alert and laravel?

I want to add 2 links in sweet alert. but I see this picture.

[image: sweet alert]

```
alert()->warning("You must register now.<br>", 'OK')->html()->persistent("<a href='http://localhost:8000/register' class='btn btn-primary'>register</a><a href='http://localhost:8000/login' class='btn btn-primary'>login</a>");
```

How to add login and register buttons in sweet alert.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

[uxweb/sweet-alert](https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert)

try it

```
alert()->warning("You must register now.<br><a href='http://localhost:8000/register' class='btn btn-primary'>register</a><a href='http://localhost:8000/login' class='btn btn-primary'>login</a>", 'OK')->html();
```